# How to sum rows in a group with condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by

can I ask for your help on how to sum rows within a group but with condition.

The condition is, if window is equal to 10, then retain count1 value, but if it is not equal to 10, then sum the rows with the same ID but retaining the window size of the first value (or lowest value) within the group.

I believe mutate won't work, or maybe it can be done with summarise but I'm lost on how to do it with conditions.

This is the code I had but I'm stuck as this will create a new column.

```
result_df1 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(new_count1 = ifelse(window==10, count1, sum(count1)))
```

An example data:

In this following table, **id 4** have its values in count1 and count2 summed in `result_df1` since both of its window is not equal to 10.

df1

| id | window | count1 | count2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2 | 30 |
| 1 | 230 | 53 | 3 |
| 2 | 430 | 40 | 5 |
| 3 | 10 | 3 | 94 |
| 4 | 370 | 32 | 4 |
| 4 | 380 | 14 | 3 |

result_df1 (This is the result that I want)

| id | window | count1 | count2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2 | 30 |
| 1 | 230 | 53 | 3 |
| 2 | 430 | 40 | 5 |
| 3 | 10 | 3 | 94 |
| 4 | 370 | 46 | 7 |

Thank you so much for help!

Answer (score 4):

You can `group_by` whether `window == 10`, and then `sum`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id, tmp = window == 10) %>% 
  summarise(window = min(window),
            across(contains("count"), sum)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-tmp)
```

Alternatively:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(tmp = window == 10) %>% 
  summarise(window = min(window),
            across(contains("count"), sum), .by = c(id, tmp)) %>% 
  select(-tmp)
```

---

output

```r
#   id window count1 count2
# 1  1     10      2     30
# 2  1    230     53      3
# 3  2    430     40      5
# 4  3     10      3     94
# 5  4    370     46      7
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `by`.

```
by(d, d$id, \(x) {
  if (all(x$window != 10)) {
   data.frame(c(x[1, 1:2], colSums(x[, 3:4])))
  } else {
    x
  }
}) |> do.call(what='rbind')
#     id window count1 count2
# 1.1  1     10      2     30
# 1.2  1    230     53      3
# 2    2    430     40      5
# 3    3     10      3     94
# 4    4    370     46      7
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), window = c(10L, 
230L, 430L, 10L, 370L, 380L), count1 = c(2L, 53L, 40L, 3L, 32L, 
14L), count2 = c(30L, 3L, 5L, 94L, 4L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```